# How to vertically centre random images of unknown sizes

Tags: html, css, flickr

I have searched for a solution for this CSS issue but the solutions I have found do not seem to work in my situation.

I am pulling in random images from Flickr. Some of them are portrait, some are landscape.
When the pictures selected include both portrait and landscape images I want to ensure they are all centred vertically.

I have read that

```
vertical-align:middle; 
display:table-cell;
```

on the container should make this work, but in my case it doesn't - perhaps some of the other CSS in place is stopping this working.

I have created a JSFiddle to show my problem: http://jsfiddle.net/alexbfree/C35DR/2/

Can you help?

Alex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code with `table-cell` can do the trick but you need to remove the `float` property:

```
div.flickr_badge_image {
  width:23.8%;
  margin: 0 1.5% 1.5% 0;
  /*float:left; Remove this*/
}
```

Check this **[Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/C35DR/3/)**

Now if you want to keep the `float` you can also do this to center the `a` tags inside:

```
div.flickr_badge_image:before {
  content:" ";
  display:inline-block;
  height:100%;
  background:red;
  vertical-align:middle;
}
div.flickr_badge_image a {
  display:inline-block;
  vertical-align:middle;
}
```

Check **[Demo Fiddle2](http://jsfiddle.net/C35DR/5/)**

Comment: Thank you so much! That is exactly what I need! Thanks!

Just one question, can you explain the content:" " part? I'm not familiar with that property....

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I cant comment yet.

Do you want something like this?

```
<center>
<div id="box-2148-0-0-0" class="module ui rounded embossed shadow yellow  module-box">
```

http://jsfiddle.net/C35DR/4/

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to look at this. I actually wanted the images centred in rows, sorry if I wasn't clear.